# 2006 Honda Odyssey sliding door stuck at *top*

Tags: honda, repair, door, odyssey

Yesterday I replaced the [roller assembly](http://amzn.com/B00F68FCJU) in the left-side sliding door of my 2006 Honda Odyssey, because it had been sticking and not rolling very well.  One of the white rollers was indeed shattered when I took it out, so it did need to be replaced.

However, the door is still sticking when we try to open it.  A closer inspection shows that the ***top*** corner (toward the rear of the car) hits the door frame, causing the door to stop and return to the closed position.  If we push (not very hard) on the top corner from inside the car, the door opens just fine.  It always closes fine.

Has anyone run across this?  Is there another piece that can be replaced, or an adjustment that can be made, to change the clearance at the top corner?

Comment: We have replaced lots of these with no problem, it is a common failure. Is the part a new OEM unit or...  ?  Is the lower rear corner closer to frame? Compare to the other door. Is the door closer to the side of the car when open?

Comment: I'll check - I should mention that it was sticking this same way for a couple of weeks before I replaced the roller, but I hadn't noticed it and I assumed it was just the roller assembly.

Comment: Did you check the rail itself? Is it clean? Did the broken rollers scar it? How about the pivot? is it greased?

Answer (score 1):

Check all the rollers, look at how the door sits compared to the body when closed, adjust the rollers as needed. if totally stuck either find a certified automotive tech or get a service manual. I used to buy individual manuals at Alldatadiy

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It looks like you might have some good info here!  Could you expand a bit as to how one might check these things?  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Get another roller from the dealership or local junkyard. Until so your gonna have problems. Oh can be ordered from Ebay as well.